# Regex: construct URL for hadoop streaming job

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to construct a url to submit as input to a hadoop streaming job.
I would like to provide as input all the data for the hour `range 08-11`.
eg:

```
s3://some-bucket/some-folder/month=2015-05-01/hour=[08-11]
```

for 04-08 I did
`s3://some-bucket/some-folder/month=2015-05-01/hour=0[4-8]` and it worked.

Is there a way to do the same the `8-11 range`.

Comment: What you are doing is actually not about regex, it's an example of [shell globbing][1]. I don't think this has support for the expansion that you're trying to do.


  [1]: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html

Answer (score 0):

08 ~ 11 is not a Number but Strings!

and You may want to match only Numeric strings which value is `8`, `9`, `10`, `11`

so...

`0[8-9]|1[0-2]`

is the expression you may want.

Comment: I tried that, since the input has to be passed as a command line argument, *nix mistakes the | as a pipe symbol

Comment: its similar to this 
/usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop 
jar /usr/lib/hadoop/hadoop-streaming.jar 
-input s3n://some-bucket/some-folder/date=2015-05-10/hour=1[6-9]/ 
-output s3n://some-bucket/some-other-folder/data_2015_05_10_16_to_19/ 
-mapper DoSomethingMapper.py 
-file DoSomethingMapper.py 
-reducer DoSomethingReducer.py 
-file DoSomethingReducer.py